# In android studio in mainactivity why the menu after the R not exist ? (R.menu)

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using android studio on windows 8.1

The error is on the menu after the R (R.menu) the menu is in red not exist.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Another missing error is in this part

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The action_settings does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you are declaring the wrong package in your Activity.

Make sure the package com.example.blah; declaration in your Activity matches the package declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml.

**Update**

Declare the R class in those activities, fragments or whatever classes that use any resource defined there.

So, it would be like:

```
package com.web_server.webserver;

// lots of imports...
// ...
import com.myproject.R;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be fine in the mainactivity i see at the top: package com.web_server.webserver; and in the AndroidManifest.xml i see the same package: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.web_server.webserver">